# how to define schema name in procedureName of @NamedStoredProcedureQuery to be read dynamically from application.properities of springboot

Tags: spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

How to pass the schema name in @NamedStoredProcedureQuery dynamically from the springbtoo application.properities

@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "XYZ", procedureName ="<SCHEMA_NAME>SP_INSIGHT_MASTER_PROCEDURE", parameters = {
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "qaz", type = Long.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "wsx", type = String.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "edc", type = String.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "rfv", type = Long.class) }))}